# New Firefox and poor Jquery performance

Tags: javascript, jquery

I don't know if anyone has this problem: 
after upgrading to new version of Firefox (15.0) I have serious Jquery performance issues on almost all my web pages (my slideshow's are choppy to say the least). I have tried to reinstall browser,running it in safe mode I have even downloaded Firefox 16.0 beta but the problem persist. In every other browser including IE8 all is fine and animations are smooth.
***But if I downgrade Firefox to 1.13.1 everything runs fine.***
Some of my sites with poor **slideshow** performance: 
http://www.homepagepays.robertpeic.com/index.html
http://robertpeic.com/newlife/
http://wowslider.com/jquery-slider-noble-fade-demo.html (not my site but also has choppy slides on my rig on Firefox 15.0)
My question's are: Did I do something wrong or is it browser fault?
 Does anyone else had this problem?
**How can I solve this without downgrading Firefox?**
Thank You all!!

Comment: I just upgraded to FF 15 on Windows and checked wowslider.com. It was nice and smooth for me.

Comment: THX guys for all your help obviously I will have to reinstall my Windows:( What a mess...